# java, compose image from several images

Tags: java, swing, javafx, imagej

I haven't experience with processing images in java. My goal is to combine several images. To be more detail, I have a template image and some other images. I want to put those images into template image at specific places.
For e.g:

**template image**:

[image]

**specific image**:

[image]

So, I want to put the dog image onto cats' image places and store the created image.

Please, tell me what is the **easiest way** to do that?

Comment: can you please tell us where those images are? e.g. from the internet? from your local directory?

Comment: @YuZhang: the images are stored at my local directory.

Comment: `Please, tell me what is the easiest way to do that?` Please, post what you have tried

Comment: What information is available? Identifying repeating pattern in the image could detect the cats, but it would also find other similar patterns, e.g. `Kot` and the stars containing 9. I'm afraid according to the current description, this is neither an easy task nor is this a good question (missing details, tag spam, a bit broad).

Comment: *"Please, tell me what is the **easiest way** to do that?"* Hire someone to write the code. For help here, show some effort and ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: @AndrewThompson. I don't want that someone write cone. Just, want to see the proposed approaches. For e.g: "for such image manipulation it is better to user javaFX"...

Comment: @fabian. The template image I have received from the designer. In my app Application I have `Card` entity, which has `name`, `imagePath`, `level` fields. So, I want to take one of the `card` objs, get the image from the local directory using `card.imagePath`, put it to the template and change `Kot` to the `card.name`, `9` to the `card.level`. So, these `stars` and `Kot` is the representations of the `card` entity fields.

Comment: @Frakcool. I have found several libraries: JavaFx, Swing, ImageJ. But which one is better to choose for such operations.

Answer (score 6):

As Fabian pointed out, identifying patterns mightn't give the expected results, so my suggestion would be an alternative

If you control the templates and provide them to the user as options, you could implement them yourself and populate the images in placeholder nodes. The merged image would come from taking an overall snapshot

I've included a quick example, but note that it's **not fully implemented** (layout etc) so consider it more as a *proof of concept*. It's still possible to build on the below to display different images at the same time, text decoration, stars etc to be a closer representation of the example image you provided

This may not be the **easiest** method, but it could be an enjoyable learning experience. This could also be a viable option since you don't have image processing experience in Java

---

```
public class ImageTemplateNode extends Region{
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Image> displayedImageProperty;
    private ObservableList<Node> children = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int rows, columns;
    private final int maximumRotation = 15;

    public ImageTemplateNode(int rows, int cols, Image imageToDisplay){
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = cols;
        this.displayedImageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(imageToDisplay);
        createDisplayNodes();
        setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(getChildren(), children);
    }

    public ImageTemplateNode(int rows, int cols, Image imageToDisplay, Image backgroundImage){
        this(rows, cols, imageToDisplay);
        setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage);
    }

    private void createDisplayNodes(){
        for(int count = 0; count < (rows * columns); count++){
            StackPane container = new StackPane();
            container.setRotate(getRandomRotationValue());
            container.setBackground(
                    new Background(new BackgroundFill(getRandomColour(), new CornerRadii(5), new Insets(5))));
            container.maxWidthProperty().bind(displayedImageProperty.get().widthProperty().add(25));
            container.maxHeightProperty().bind(displayedImageProperty.get().heightProperty().add(25));

            ImageView displayNode = new ImageView();
            displayNode.imageProperty().bind(displayedImageProperty);
            displayNode.fitWidthProperty().bind(container.widthProperty().subtract(25));
            displayNode.fitHeightProperty().bind(container.heightProperty().subtract(25));

            container.getChildren().setAll(displayNode);
            children.add(container);
        }
    }

    private int getRandomRotationValue(){
        int randomValue = random.nextInt(maximumRotation);
        //Rotate clockwise if even, anti-clockwise if odd
        return randomValue % 2 == 0 ? randomValue : 360 - randomValue;
    }

    private Color getRandomColour(){
        int red = random.nextInt(256);
        int green = random.nextInt(256);
        int blue = random.nextInt(256);
        return Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        //Calculate the dimensions for the children so that they do not breach the padding and allow for rotation
        double cellWidth = (widthProperty().doubleValue()
                - getPadding().getLeft() - getPadding().getRight() - maximumRotation) / columns;
        double cellHeight = (heightProperty().doubleValue()
                - getPadding().getTop() - getPadding().getBottom() - maximumRotation) / rows;

        for (int i = 0; i < (rows); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (columns); j++) {
                if (children.size() <= ((i * (columns)) + j)) {
                    break;
                }
                Node childNode = children.get((i * (columns)) + j);
                layoutInArea(childNode,
                        (j * cellWidth) + getPadding().getLeft(),
                        (i * cellHeight) + getPadding().getTop(), cellWidth, cellHeight,
                        0.0d, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setBackgroundImage(Image backgroundImage){
        setBackground(new Background(
                new BackgroundImage(backgroundImage,
                        BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
                        BackgroundSize.DEFAULT)));
    }

    public void changeDisplayImage(Image newImageToDisplay){
        displayedImageProperty.set(newImageToDisplay);
    }

    public void captureAndSaveDisplay(){
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        //Set extension filter
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png"));

        //Prompt user to select a file
        File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        if(file != null){
            try {
                //Pad the capture area
                WritableImage writableImage = new WritableImage((int)getWidth() + 20,
                        (int)getHeight() + 20);
                snapshot(null, writableImage);
                RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(writableImage, null);
                //Write the snapshot to the chosen file
                ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", file);
            } catch (IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Screen shots:

[image]
[image]

Saved snap shots:

[image]
[image]